# sharepoint 2013 document library creating custom edit forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, custom

i am using sharepoint 2013 online and i am having issues  creating a custom edit form for a document library.
My document library contains around twenty fields. i have 2 edit forms (editform.aspx & specialedit.aspx). the editform.aspx is the default edit form and allows the user to submit data to all 20 fields in the document library. the specialedit.aspx is a custom edit form i created in sharepoint designer and this form only has 2 fields on it which the user can submit data to. the problem i am having is when i click on the save button on the specialedit.aspx form i am prompted to open a document instead of saving the data entered.
Has anyone else experienced this before , just wondering if sharepoint allows document library to have more than 1 edit form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution , you can add a custom save button with javascript in sharepoint designer which saves changes and then closes the browser.

`<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Save Changes" id="Submit1" style="width:140px" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}; window.alert('Item updated.') ; window.close();" />`